# Passing Data from PHP to Python

Tags: php, python, sockets, ipc, tcp

I am currently trying to decide on best way to send data across from a PHP script to a Python script. But please keep reading as I have already looked at existing posts on the subject. Currently I am doing the following as suggested by one of the posts I have read:

```
Example .php
$var1 = 2;
$tmp = exec(/var/www Example.py $var1);
echo "$tmp";

Example.py
import sys
print sys.argv[1]
```

This seems to be working ok. Although it is in the really early stages. 
Ultimately the PHP script will be sending over a reasonable amount of data generated from an HTML form so I wondered if it was the most efficient way of sending it.

The PHP, HTML and the Python scripts are running on a [`Raspberry Pi`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi) which is connected via a wired LAN to a laptop.

Ultimately I am going to have to use TCP/IP to read various commands from another desktop that will be sending them out via TCP/IP (I can't change this) so I wondered whether it was better to initialize sockets now and then use this method to also send the data from the PHP script to Python.

I am quite new to this range of languages so I am only looking for advice so that I can then investigate further. I have looked at various other posts but none seem to match what I am trying to do.

Comment: Do you have to use PHP, or could you use Python as the server side programming language?

Comment: unless you need the flexibility of moving one of the processes to another machine, you don't need sockets. reading stdin, writing to stdout should be fine.

Comment: Hi user2387370, unfortunately I have already coded it all in html/php so I want to stay with php if I can. I did look at replacing it all with Python but if I can do what I want in php there should be no need.

Comment: Hi Karoly Horvath, I thought that might be the case with regards to sockets. I will need to use them later though as I need to be able to be able to communicate data through TCP/IP which I assume would need sockets? For moving the data from php to Python I am only accessing a different application on the same system.

Comment: Hi xaxxon, having read up on pipes since your comment I think this might be the way I will go. I will put a bit of test code together and see if I can get it working the way I want.

Comment: What is the Python script doing? Does it need the data synchronously? Your PHP program could post into a database and the Python could poll it.

Answer (score 0):

Try [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/)

> ØMQ (also known as ZeroMQ, 0MQ, or zmq) looks like an embeddable
>   networking library but acts like a concurrency framework. It gives you
>   sockets that carry atomic messages across various transports like
>   in-process, inter-process, TCP, and multicast. You can connect sockets
>   N-to-N with patterns like fan-out, pub-sub, task distribution, and
>   request-reply. It's fast enough to be the fabric for clustered
>   products. Its asynchronous I/O model gives you scalable multicore
>   applications, built as asynchronous message-processing tasks. It has a
>   score of language APIs and runs on most operating systems. ØMQ is from
>   iMatix and is LGPLv3 open source.

or [nanomsg](http://nanomsg.org/) (new project from author of zeromq)

> nanomsg is a socket library that provides several common communication
>   patterns. It aims to make the networking layer fast, scalable, and
>   easy to use. Implemented in C, it works on a wide range of operating
>   systems with no further dependencies.

similar question with examples: [Sending data to Python Script from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20428414/sending-data-to-python-script-from-php)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a queuing service like [Gearman](http://gearman.org/), with a client in PHP and a worker in Python or vice versa.

Someone has created an example setup here.

https://github.com/dbaltas/gearman-python-worker

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the PHP part is some sort of web application. If that is the case I'd isolate the python scripts as CGI scripts/endpoints and communicate with them, pass and receive data using standard HTTP requests. So you Python script would become:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Import modules for CGI handling 
import cgi, cgitb, json 

# Create instance of FieldStorage 
form = cgi.FieldStorage() 

# Get data from fields
var1 = form.getvalue('var1')

# Process data and possibly and up with complex output
obj = {'one':1, 'two':2}

# Make it output json  
print "Content-type: application/json"
print 
print(json.JSONEncoder().encode(obj))
```

And you call from php something like:

```
// Get cURL resource
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://localhost/cgi-bin/example.py?var1=2',
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'My Internal Request'
));
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

That will allow you to pass complex data structures to python scripts and receive structured responses (json). Also it will modularize python part of your app and allow for reuse. And the best part is you have CGI endpoints so you can as well use sockets to communicate with them.