# Sending data to Python Script from PHP

Tags: php, python, sockets

Here is my problem, I have a Python script that will be running indefinitely in a `while(1)` loop. I want some PHP script to somehow interact with the Python script, and when it does, the script needs to perform a function with the data submitted to the script.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: are both scripts located on the same host?

Comment: You would probably be better doing the interactions with a database. I don't know how PHP can be used to interact with an already running Python script, unless that Python script is somehow listening for incoming connections. We need more details of what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: I think the database idea would be good actually. Perhaps listening for new entries with a tag of NOT_STARTED perhaps? I am making a (legit) mail bomber. User submits a request and the python script executes said request. When a new entry is found by the script, a new mail bomber thread will be started. And yes, both scripts are on the same host.

Comment: What's the data type? JSON?

Comment: Please clarify: which script does the data come from, what kind of data and how many items are there, does anything need to be returned, what sort of response time is needed, how often will you be calling it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [redis](https://redis.io/) (pub/sub feature for example) as interprocess communication facility.

> Redis is an open source (BSD licensed), in-memory data structure
>   store, used as a database, cache and message broker. It supports data
>   structures such as strings, hashes, lists, sets, sorted sets with
>   range queries, bitmaps, hyperloglogs and geospatial indexes with
>   radius queries. Redis has built-in replication, Lua scripting, LRU
>   eviction, transactions and different levels of on-disk persistence,
>   and provides high availability via Redis Sentinel and automatic
>   partitioning with Redis Cluster.

Besides of IPC via redis you can use it as distributed key-value database - big advantage of redis imho.

Another choice - [zeromq](http://zeromq.org/) - one of most known tools for interprocess communication. There is many tutorials and docs about it on internet. Original guide: http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all

> ØMQ (also known as ZeroMQ, 0MQ, or zmq) looks like an embeddable
>   networking library but acts like a concurrency framework. It gives you
>   sockets that carry atomic messages across various transports like
>   in-process, inter-process, TCP, and multicast. You can connect sockets
>   N-to-N with patterns like fan-out, pub-sub, task distribution, and
>   request-reply. It's fast enough to be the fabric for clustered
>   products. Its asynchronous I/O model gives you scalable multicore
>   applications, built as asynchronous message-processing tasks. It has a
>   score of language APIs and runs on most operating systems. ØMQ is from
>   iMatix and is LGPLv3 open source.

Hello world server and client on python: https://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pyzmq/patterns/client_server.html

Simple example of PHP server and python client from official guide:

PHP server:

```
<?php
/*
*  Hello World server
*  Binds REP socket to tcp://*:5555
*  Expects "Hello" from client, replies with "World"
* @author Ian Barber <ian(dot)barber(at)gmail(dot)com>
*/

$context = new ZMQContext(1);

//  Socket to talk to clients
$responder = new ZMQSocket($context, ZMQ::SOCKET_REP);
$responder->bind("tcp://*:5555");

while (true) {
    //  Wait for next request from client
    $request = $responder->recv();
    printf ("Received request: [%s]\n", $request);

    //  Do some 'work'
    sleep (1);

    //  Send reply back to client
    $responder->send("World");
}
```

Hello World client in Python:

```
#
#   Hello World client in Python
#   Connects REQ socket to tcp://localhost:5555
#   Sends "Hello" to server, expects "World" back
#
import zmq

context = zmq.Context()

#  Socket to talk to server
print "Connecting to hello world server…"
socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
socket.connect("tcp://localhost:5555")

#  Do 10 requests, waiting each time for a response
for request in range(10):
    print "Sending request %s …" % request
    socket.send("Hello")

    #  Get the reply.
    message = socket.recv()
    print "Received reply %s [ %s ]" % (request, message)
```

Comment: ZeroMQ (and also RabbitMQ) are MOM (Message Oriented Middleware). They only cares about transporting the message. It is up to you build a "protocol" in order to know what to do in response to a message.

Answer (score 1):

Use xml-rpc.

Expose your python object and consume it from PHP using some xmlrpc client. Security is up to you. ;)

Php example at:  http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.webservices.xml-rpc.examples.php

Python doc at: http://docs.python.org/2/library/xmlrpclib.html

Comment: Xml-rpc has a lot of encode/decode overhead; depending on how complex his data types are, it may not be worth it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use python's `SimpleHTTPServer` in your python script to run the server forever on some port. Then your PHP code can interact with python on HTTP. Both scripts dont need to be on the same host. You can look [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html) for more on this

Answer (score 0):

If the same machine, you can use file with command. Create a file cmd.txt , python will read it in loop every sec, Php script will write a command in file cmd.txt , python will do the job and erase the command from cmd.txt

Answer (score 0):

I would use Twisted to turn the Python code into a service which can then be called by your PHP code.

See example code at http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/

Comment: Don't you thing Twisted to much for only use the service part. Python already have http and xmlrpc servers that don't require so much reading as twisted.